# Como se traduz «boleto bancário» para inglês?

Tags: português-brasileiro, tradução, tradução-inglês

Certa vez estava precisando dizer que:

> Um boleto bancário será impresso após você clicar neste botão, e também será enviado ao seu email.

Pensando nisso, a mensagem ao usuário deveria surtir o mesmo efeito em outra língua: entender que pressionando o botão, vai imprimir um boleto bancário e também enviá-lo no email.

O problema é que não encontrei nenhuma tradução que, ao meu senso, fizesse sentido. O Translate traduzia boleto para *ticket*, e boleto bancário para *bank slip*.

Já tinha visto algumas discussões relacionadas a isso, mas gostaria de uma informação mais apurada e com mais embasamento e tangível, sobre qual a tradução (mais próxima possível) para boleto bancário?

---

Então, qual é a tradução (que surta maior efeito) para boleto **e** boleto bancário?

Comment: Eu trabalho com projetos em vários países e até onde eu sei, boleto é algo bem do Brasil. Tu poderias traduzir para "bank slip" ou "payment slip", mas não seria exatamente a mesma tradução. 
Para mim, a melhor tradução seria: it is an invoice sent by a bank on behalf of a third-party business, payable using a bar code.
Temos esse problema com outros termos, Nota Fiscal é um bom exemplo. Podemos traduzir para Invoice, mas a Nota Fiscal Brasileira é muito mais complexa e com obrigações que uma Invoice nos EUA.

Comment: Realmente é muito trabalhoso essa parte @Peixoto. Os termos acabam com qualquer um quando se quer gerar o mesmo efeito.

Comment: @Peixoto, pesquisando eu encontrei *banking billet* também.

Comment: Seria melhor perguntares isto no [English Language Use](https://english.stackexchange.com/) , lá vais ter melhores resultados. Explicas **bem** o que queres, e eles encontram-te a palavra certa. Aqui vais ter muita gente que percebe bem a palavra original, mas poucos que sabem como o dizer em inglês.

Comment: Eu perguntei mas não fui respondido @ANeves. A pergunta seguia esse padrão que estou a perguntar aqui. Perguntei também sobre o elevator pitch. Mas sem respostas a ambas.

Answer (score 4):

"Bill" é um termo geral para "conta" em inglês que se aplica a boleto bancário, o significado é muito próximo, embora geral, a não ser que você precise de um termo que contenha intrinsecamente o significado exato (jurídico, bancário, normas, etc) de boleto no Brasil, que acredito não existir.

Olhe esta especialização de "bill" no termo [bank bill](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bank+bill)

Uma alternativa é procurar por documentos e orientações da Febraban, talvez eles tenham algum conceito/frase/termo para isto em inglês.

Outras variações possíveis:

- Boleto (não traduza)
- Slip or Bank slip
- Bill of exchange
- Bank voucher
- Bank billing
- Bank billet

E outros.

**EDIT:**
Diversos sites de comércio eletrônico estrangeiros, adaptados para oferecer opção de boleto para o Brasil, mesmo quando apresentam o conteúdo em inglês, usam o termo "boleto".

*Boleto* no contexto bancário passou a ser um nome de um sistema de pagamentos e não uma palavra corriqueira do dicionário que possamos traduzir, exemplo o sistema atual em desenvolvimento PIX.

Comment: banck slip? Correto assim?

Comment: Erro de digitação. Corrigido. Obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

O termo que *eu* usaria neste caso é [**invoice**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/invoice).

Apesar de não ser tão parecido com uma traducão direta, é o termo que em geral as empresas usam quando mandam boletos (ou contas) de uma para outras. Vale notar que isso é em geral usado na Europa, não tenho certeza se nos EUA isto teria o mesmo sentido ou invoice se traduziria melhor para "nota fiscal".

Por exemplo:

> Payment through invoice

Em geral vai ser um processo similar (ou igual) a gerar o boleto bancário. As vezes é uma conta que você tem que pagar pelo banco com uma transferência ou então a conta é mandada diretamente para a o setor de contas da empresa.