# Como dizer "emissão de nota fiscal" em inglês?

Tags: tradução

No Brasil, temos diversos modelos de nota fiscal para os demais estados. O termo "nota fiscal" se refere a todos os diferentes tipos.

Não consigo achar uma boa tradução para a língua inglesa desse termo.

Em inglês, como posso dizer "emissão de nota fiscal" em um contexto comercial?

Comment: Tu queres traduzir a Nota Fiscal Brasileira para o Inglês? A Nota Fiscal Brasileira é muito mais complexa que uma Invoice nos Estados Unidos. A tradução literal seria "to issue an invoice". Por outro lado, trabalho com outros países e já nem traduzimos Nota Fiscal, utlizamos palavra em Português mesmo, dando a ideia da complexidade.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Resposta curta

Eu provavelmente usaria **invoice** e em algumas situações mais específicas **receipt**.

---

## Resposta mais longa

O problema é que a nota fiscal, como existe no Brasil, é um documento com características únicas que possui fins fiscais e contábeis.

A nota-fiscal possui características tanto do **invoice** quanto do **receipt**.

O *receipt* está mais para o cupom fiscal, notinha, comprovante de pagamento, mas também pode designar o que chamamos por "nota-fiscal", especialmente em transações envolvendo varejo e produtos de menor valor. Por exemplo: ao comprar um par de sapatos em uma loja comum, o consumidor receberá um *receipt*.

Já o termo *invoice* pode definir um documento que inclua diversos produtos envolvidos na transação e também a prestação de serviços. Aqui, ela é bem próxima do que chamamos de Nota-Fiscal. Por exemplo: Uma empresa que entrega os bens junto com a *invoice* na qual constam os bens entregues e as suas características (número de série, valor, quantidade, etc.)

Outro ponto importante é que a *invoice* não necessariamente é emitida numa transação com pagamento imediato. Pode tratar-se de pedido de pagamento em face da transação e aí ela seria equivalente à "fatura". Por exemplo: Um advogado emite a *invoice* com as horas de trabalho para pagamento pelo cliente. Ou uma companhia emite uma *invoice* tratando de mercadorias que ainda serão entregues.

**Importante**, em caso de documento emitido para fins fiscais, e dependendo do conteúdo dele, pode ser necessário o uso dos termos **tax invoice** ou **tax receipt**.

Eu recomendo que seja analisado o contexto para decidir o que escolher. Também é recomendável uma análise da legislação local. No Brasil, por exemplo, há uma série de regras quanto aos termos e formatação usados na Nota-Fiscal.

---

Fontes:

- O verbete ["invoice" na wikipedia em Inglês](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invoice) é bem completo.
- http://dictionary.cambridge.org/pt/dicionario/ingles/receipt
- http://dictionary.cambridge.org/pt/dicionario/ingles/invoice

Answer (score 1):

[Invoice](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/invoice?s=t) é provavelmente o que você quer.

Como foi colocado no comentário, não é obvia, pois se você for traduzir do inglês para o português, invoice pode ser traduzido como fatura, ou ainda como [boleto bancário](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/4786/2386).

Answer (score 1):

Literalmente, a tradução para o inglês para *emissão de nota fiscal* é *invoice issuance*.

Utilizando o Linguee, podemos ver alguns exemplos de tradução:

> Emissão de nota fiscal de venda, obrigatoriamente...

traduzido para:

> Mandatory issuance of sales invoices to client

Fonte: [Linguee](http://www.linguee.com.br/portugues-ingles/traducao/emiss%C3%A3o+de+nota+fiscal.html)

Porém, a Nota Fiscal utilizada no Brasil é bem complexa e diferente do que temos ao redor do mundo. Então vale a explicação, dizendo que há recolhimento de imposto e pode ser utilizado como meio de cobrança. Já a Invoice (nos EUA) é separadamente. Pode ter a emissão de uma *Invoice* apenas para movimentação de mercadorias e um *Billing* para cobrança.